# Use Vaadin with google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, vaadin

I'm just wondering if its possible to have a Vaadin project working under google app engine? If it is then please refer me to any kind of documentation or "how-to".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Vaadin wiki](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Google%20AppEngine%20HOWTO) contains a step-by-step process.

Answer (score 4):

There is an ticket about supporting Vaadin by GAE: http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/2835

I've tried it - and id works. First of all you need to enable sessions:

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
```

and use `GAEApplicationServlet` instead of default vaadin's.

Second: make sure that all you domain objects, are serializable (i bet it's no problem, btw)

And third: move all static files (theme css and images) from vaadin's jar to your webapp folder

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [it is possible](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Google%20AppEngine%20HOWTO).
To start with something easy, read the [tutorial](http://vaadin.com/tutorial) to create a simple address book and download the project for Google App Engine [here](http://code.google.com/p/simpleaddressbook/).

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that it works. 
There are only a few things to consider, all described in http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.gae.html. When it comes to persistence, things get a bit more tricky. You might have a look at http://code.google.com/p/instant-webapp/ where most things have been adressed and more or less solved.

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can use Vaadin donot know of specific gae\vaadin doc but it's not different to running vaadin on your machine it's just GWT based rich ajax liberary

Comment: As Vaadin is stateful framework, it's heavily depends on sessions and serialization, and it doesn't work out-of-box on gae

Comment: @splix you are wrong it works out of the box. Do not let me low repute fool you.